# WPF - set changed event handler for single entry in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

In my wpf application, I want to write changed event handler for my listbox entry. This entry consist of comboboxes and TimePickers. My listbox linked with some web account so all entries of listbox saved there. When I try to save my edited entry, all the entries are saved. To avoid this problem,I want to write changed event handler so that it will give me only updated entry. how to write changed event handler for only edited entry instead of all entries.

xaml for listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick">
                    </EventSetter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

ListBox contains below in single entry-

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" Value="{Binding StartValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" Value="{Binding EndValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="130" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: the question is not clear, please add more description

Comment: Yes, please explain what you mean by 'single entry'.

Comment: There are many entries in listbox. Single entry means a entry consist of textboxes, comboboxes and TimePickers. In this case,it's edited entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general practice to keep a flag, that shows is there any changes in data or not.
MVVM-style sample could be like this:

1) The base view model, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

2) The view model of your list entry. Note, that here's `HasChanges` property. When any other view bound property has changed, `HasChanges` becomes `true`:

```
public class MyListEntryViewModel : ViewModel
{        
    public string ClientName
    {
        get { return clientName; }
        set
        {
            if (clientName != value)
            {
                clientName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ClientName");
            }
        }
    }
    private string clientName;

    // the rest of bindable properties (ApplicationName, StartPicker, etc.)

    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get { return hasChanges; }
        set
        {
            if (hasChanges != value)
            {
                hasChanges = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasChanges");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool hasChanges;

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName != "HasChanges")
        {
            HasChanges = true;
        }
    }
}
```

3) The view model of your editor (the thing, that keeps your list entries and a commands for adding, deleting, saving, etc.):

```
public class MyEditorViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        var changedItems = Items
            .Where(item => item.HasChanges);

        // send changed items to server
    }

    private bool CanSaveChanges()
    {
        return Items.Any(item => item.HasChanges);
    }

    public MyEditorViewModel()
    {
        SaveChangesCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveChanges, CanSaveChanges);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyListEntryViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items ?? (items = new ObservableCollection<MyListEntryViewModel>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MyListEntryViewModel> items;

    public RelayCommand SaveChangesCommand { get; private set; }
}
```